# Why am I getting a module not found error when I try to use Conv1D from Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to import `Conv1D` from `keras.layers` like this:

`import tensorflow.keras.convolutional.Conv1D`

However, I can't solve this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.convolutional'`

I tried updating `Python`, `Keras`, and `TensorFlow` to the latest version, but I still get the same error. I also tried to import it like this:

`from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D`

Comment: `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import `Conv1D` from `keras.layers` use below command

> from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D

Make sure you TensorFlow is correctly  installed, as Keras is integrated into TensorFlow.
If you are still facing the issue ,please check the [tensorflow official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install).And one more think you may attempt resolving the issue by restarting your Python environment or employing a virtual environment to isolate your project dependencies.